# Timer without threading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to programming and would like to add a counter that deducts 1 from your score every two seconds. (so that I have to answer quickly to make my score increase)

```
chr
import random
import time
radians2 = None
ans = None
score = 0

radians1 = ['0', 'π/6', 'π/3', 'π/4', 'π/2', '2π/3', '3π/4', '5π/6', 'π', '7π/6', '4π/3', '5π/4', '3π/2', '5π/3', '7π/4', '11π/6', '2π']
while radians2 == ans or ans == None:

radians3 = (random.choice(radians1))
ans = input(radians3)
if radians3 == '0':
    radians2 = 0

elif radians3 == 'π/6':
    radians2 = 30

elif radians3 == 'π/3':
    radians2 = 60

elif radians3 == 'π/4':
    radians2 = 45

elif radians3 == 'π/2':
    radians2 = 90

elif radians3 == '2π/3':
    radians2 = 120

elif radians3 == '3π/4':
    radians2 = 135

elif radians3 == '5π/6':
    radians2 = 150

elif radians3 == 'π':
    radians2 = 180

elif radians3 == '7π/6':
    radians2 = 210

elif radians3 == '4π/3':
    radians2 = 240

elif radians3 == '5π/4':
    radians2 = 225

elif radians3 == '3π/2':
    radians2 = 270

elif radians3 == '5π/3':
    radians2 = 300

elif radians3 == '7π/4':
    radians2 = 315

elif radians3 == '11π/6':
    radians2 = 330

elif radians3 == '2π':
    radians2 = 360
score = score + 1

if radians2 == ans:
    print('Correct!')
    print "You've got %d in a row" % score
print "You lose, the correct answer was %d" % radians2
```

Sorry if the code is messy/long
I figured out that I want to basically run something like:

```
while 1:
     time.sleep(2)
     score = score - 1
```

The only problem is that won't run simultaneously with the rest of the program, and threading (which is what seems to be the alternative) is very confusing to me.

Comment: Sorry, but "simultaneously" means you need threading. And yes, threading can be confusing, but it is worse to dive into it.

Comment: The alternative to threading - a mainloop - is probably a lot more confusing. Threading isn't all that hard.

Comment: um, can't you just measure the time (`time.clock()` or `datetime.datetime.now()`) before asking the user and then again afterwards?  The difference is the time it took them to answer, there is no need for threads or loops here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start new thread , by using following code and write whatever your functional logic in it's run() method.

```
import threading
import time

class RepeatEvery(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)     
        self.interval = interval  # seconds between calls
        self.runable = True

    def run(self):
        global score # make score global for this thread context
        while self.runable:
            time.sleep(self.interval)
            if self.runable:     
                score = score - 1
                self.runable = False

    def stop(self):
        self.runable = False
```

The above code will iterate until thread is runnable(self.runable = True), so after 2 seconds score will decremented by 1. and loop inside the run method will break, and will be terminated.

So, in order to call above thread do this.

```
score_thread = RepeatEvery(2)
score_thread.start()
```

this will call the thread constructor **init** and will initialize the interval variable with 2 seconds or whatever value passed from here.

In order to stop the thread meanwhile, just call the stop() method.

```
score_thread.stop()
```

You can also call join() method , to wait until thread completes it's execution.

```
score_thread.join()
```

Doesn't looks so confusing :)

Comment: When I try to call the thread it says that RepeatEvery is not defined. I'm not sure where in the code I should place the start lines either.

Comment: Still causing me issues, says I'm missing a module (I have threading) and says that RepeatEvery is not defined

Comment: it should work check the indentation of the class where you defined it!

Comment: Thank you, got it to work. I was trying to fit my while loop into the run() but apparently that wasn't necessary. Works now

Comment: always glad to help!

Comment: given that there's a million ways for a thread to error out, though: what's the still missing but _incredibly required_ code that makes sure the thread crashing doesn't take down the parent process too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a corutine if you dont want to use any thread, each time you call the next method of the generator it will yield the elapsed time:

```
def timer():
    prev_time = new_time = 0
    while True:
        prev_time, new_time = new_time, time.clock()
        time_delta = new_time - prev_time
        yield time_delta

>>> t = timer()
>>> t.next()
4.399568842253459e-06
>>> t.next()
1.7571719571481994
>>> t.next()
0.8449679931366727
```